# Как получить день недели первого дня прошлого месяца?

Tags: дата, objective-c, ios

Привет

Подскажите как получить первый день недели в прошлом месяце.
Например что бы получить первый день недели в данном месяце: 
[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] firstWeekday]

А как тоже самое высчитать для прошлого месяца?

Спасибо

Comment: firstWeekday - этот код возвращает какой день недели установлен как первый для данного календаря. А Вам нужно как я понимаю день недели первого числа каждого взятого месяца?

Comment: @zhenyab, вы абсолютно правы - `-[NSCalendar firstWeekday]` тут вообще не при чём.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пожалуйста, сырой пример:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];

NSDateComponents *componentsForOneMonthAgo =[[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
componentsForOneMonthAgo.month = -1;

NSDate *todayAMonthAgo = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:componentsForOneMonthAgo toDate:today options:0];

NSDateComponents *componentsForTheFirstDayOfTheMonth = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:todayAMonthAgo];
componentsForTheFirstDayOfTheMonth.day = 1;

NSDate *firstDayOfPreviousMonth = [calendar dateFromComponents:componentsForTheFirstDayOfTheMonth];

NSDateComponents *componentsOfTheFirstDayOfTheMonth = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit) fromDate:firstDayOfPreviousMonth];

NSLog(@"the 'week day' of the first day of the previous month: %d", componentsOfTheFirstDayOfTheMonth.weekday);
```

---

**А вот простейший юнит-тест для этого метода**

```
static NSDate *dateWithYear(NSUInteger year, NSUInteger month, NSUInteger day) {
    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];

    components.year = year;
    components.month = month;
    components.day = day;

    return [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
}

static NSUInteger weekDayOfTheFirstDayForAPreviousMonthForDate(NSDate *date) {
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    NSDateComponents *componentsForOneMonthAgo = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    componentsForOneMonthAgo.month = -1;

    NSDate *dateAMonthAgo = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:componentsForOneMonthAgo toDate:date options:0];

    NSDateComponents *componentsForTheFirstDayOfTheMonth = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:dateAMonthAgo];
    componentsForTheFirstDayOfTheMonth.day = 1;

    NSDate *firstDayOfPreviousMonth = [calendar dateFromComponents:componentsForTheFirstDayOfTheMonth];

    NSDateComponents *componentsOfTheFirstDayOfTheMonth = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit) fromDate:firstDayOfPreviousMonth];

    return componentsOfTheFirstDayOfTheMonth.weekday;
}

- (void)test_weekDayOfTheFirstDayForAPreviousMonthForDate {
    {
        NSDate *date = dateWithYear(2013, 9, 7);
        STAssertEquals(5, (int)weekDayOfTheFirstDayForAPreviousMonthForDate(date), nil);
    }
    {
        NSDate *date = dateWithYear(2013, 10, 7);
        STAssertEquals(1, (int)weekDayOfTheFirstDayForAPreviousMonthForDate(date), nil);
    }
    {
        NSDate *date = dateWithYear(2013, 11, 7);
        STAssertEquals(3, (int)weekDayOfTheFirstDayForAPreviousMonthForDate(date), nil);
    }
    {
        NSDate *date = dateWithYear(2013, 12, 7);
        STAssertEquals(6, (int)weekDayOfTheFirstDayForAPreviousMonthForDate(date), nil);
    }
    {
        NSDate *date = dateWithYear(2012, 9, 7);
        STAssertEquals(4, (int)weekDayOfTheFirstDayForAPreviousMonthForDate(date), nil);
    }
}
```

Comment: Сейчас я гляну еще. Возможно, что это можно свернуть в значительно меньшее число строк. Хорошо бы тесты написать для этого. Я до этого не имел дела с датами, поэтому требуется время.

Comment: Так, проверил, короче вряд ли получится - точнее я не знаю как. А вот тесты напишу в течение получаса для нескольких дат.

Comment: Спасибо, проверил, да этот вариант работает

Comment: Добавил тесты. См вторую часть обновленного ответа.

Comment: Плюс за юнит-тест.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете воспользоваться `NSDateComponents.` [Официальная документация](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html), [пример для быстрого старта](http://idev.by/ios/21054/)

Comment: @AlexThumb, ваш ответ выглядит, как быстрый гугл. Попробуйте написать ответ на основе ваших ссылок.

Comment: Разве примера для быстрого старта недостаточно? Там же все описано

Comment: Я как бы пробовал с NSdate Components. может что не правильно вычислял. потому и спросил.